How to extract text from image using pytesseract
image here
I want to extract the text from this image.I have tried many ocr liibrary but none is giving me Remotly close accuracy.
I have used Easyocr and Pytesseract and kerasocr with Preprocessing the image using the Opencv. the best result I have get is from this code
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = cv2.imread('vehicle_license.jpg')

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image, (5, 5), 0)

thresholded_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 4)

inverted_image = cv2.bitwise_not(thresholded_image)

extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(inverted_image, lang='eng')

print(extracted_text)

